# Foreign key to multiple primary keys on different tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a property management application with a full blown accounting system built into it. I have a journal entries table that controls all the postings for various accounting activities such as:

Invoices
Payments
Bills
Deposits

In some cases it's necessary to join these entities to the journal entries table to aggregate accounting entries by different properties and units.

I'm looking for the best way to do this. I have several options:

1) Add a foreign key on the journal entry table to link to the invoice_id, payment_id, bill_id, deposit_id, however most combinations of these will be mutually exclusive (i.e. a deposit would not have a payment) so I would have cases where for a given journal entry I would have nulls in those foreign keys that do not apply to that given journal entry.

2) I could create a single foreign key, let's call it doc_id and another column doc_type to indicate the type of document (Invoice, Payment, Bill, Deposit, etc) and have the combination of doc_id and the document_type_id to reference a primary key on one of the extension tables (i.e. doc_id = 1 & doc_type = Invoice that combination would reference the primary key on the Invoice table).

Which is the better way to go about this or am I thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: I'm not a db expert, just started few months ago. To see if I'm understanding your question, you got one main table (doc) and other tables connected to it with a referenced primary key with a 1:n relationship?

Comment: Yes, the main table is really the journal_entry table and the Invoice, Payment, Deposit and Bill tables need to reference corresponding entries in it, however they won't all have values for each record entered into the journal_entry table (as in option 1). 1:n, yes.

Comment: each approach has its own problems in my opinion. the first option says that in journal_entry you will have specific column for each table. so if you need to add new table with the same reference type, you will have to alter your main table and added a column for it. the second options will lead to many rows for each item. each row indicates where to look.

Comment: I would go for a connection table between the main table and the others. a table that has 3 columns: journal_id, ref_id, ref_id_type. and use it as a connection manager. this way if you need to update journals data, you will need to update only 1 row (fixes the option 2 problem) and if you want to add new table, it takes only to add 1 row in the connection table.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't you put a foreign key in Invoices, Payments, etc., pointing to the Journal table's primary key?

Comment: my mistake, I understood that the 1:n direction is from journal_entry to the tables somehow. you definitely could do it by using a forigen key as you described. sorry I confused you.

Comment: You're both right, I think I was trying to make this more complicated than it seems, a FK from each table to the journal_entry table will work exactly how I need it, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a standard base entity/sub entity pattern. There is one table, let's call it JournalEntries, which contains the attributes that all journal entries have in common: ID, type of entry, when it was created, who created it, and so on.

```
create table JournalEntries(
    ID       Int  auto_generating primary key,
    EType    char( 1 )  not null check( EType in( 'I', 'P', 'B', 'D' )) -- Invoice, Payment, etc.
    Amount   currency  not null,
    CreateDate  Date not null,
    ...,     -- other common attributes
    constraint UQ_JournalEntryType unique( ID, EType ) -- create anchor for FKs
);
```

Notice that ID is the primary key so therefore unique. So the constraint making the combination of ID and EType unique is redundant from a domain definition point of view. All it does is define an anchor for foreign keys.

These FKs will be in the subentity tables -- one table for each subentity: Invoice, Payment, Bill and Deposit. Note that if an entry is defined in the JournalEntries table as a Deposit (EType = 'D') a corresponding entry can only be made in the Deposits table. You can't, for example, mistakenly use that ID in, say, the Payments table.

Let's define one of the subentity tables:

```
create table Invoices(
    ID    int   primary key, -- value generated by JournalEntries table
    IType char( 1 ) not null check( IType = 'I' ), -- Nothing but invoices
    ...,   -- Invoice-specific attributes
    constraint FK_InvoiceToEntry foreign key( ID, IType )
      references JournalEntries( ID, EType )
);
```

Now let's create an activity that always has one Invoice associated with it and may have any number of other entries. The constraints ensure only invoices can be inserted and the ID value must match a JournalEntries entry that is defined as an Invoice.

```
create table Activities(
  ID   int   auto_generating primary key,
  InvID int  not null,
  IType char( 1 ) check( IType = 'I' ),
  ...,   -- other data
  constraint FK_ActivityInvoice foreign key( InvID, Type )
);
```

There may be any number of additional entries and they may be any of the entry types, so you need an intersection table:

```
create table ActivityEntries(
    ActID  int  not null,
    EntID  int  not null,
    DateEntered date not null,
    constraint FK_ActEntry_Activity foreign key( ActID )
      references Activities( ID ),
    constraint FK_ActEntry_JEntry foreign key( EntID )
      references JournalEntries( ID )
);
```

Note that a "Journal Entry" is the JournalEntries data joined with the associated data from one of the subentity tables. So FK references to any journal entry should refer to the JournalEntries table, not any of the subentity tables, even if you know what kind of entry it is. So the Activities rows refer to the JournalEntries table using the EType field as additional data integrity effort because it *must* be an invoice. The intersection table contains any type of entry so its FK target is just the PK.

Note: for illustration purposes, the type indicator in the JournalEntries table was constrained by a check statement. In an actual database, a much better design would be an entry types lookup table. That maintains the data integrity but is a much more flexible design. (Plus the fact that MySQL still(!) doesn't implement check constraints.)